# Better & faster way to sum & ifelse for a large set of columns in a big data frame using ddply R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

## Question

I am trying to sum each column in a data frame by group and set the value as 1 if the sum is not 0. I tried to use max function instead of the combo (sum & ifelse), but I kept getting Inf values. However, the combo takes too much time to compute, where I have 1.5m rows and 500 dummy variables to summarize.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

## Example dataset

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(tibble)
  library(data.table)
  
  rename <- dplyr::rename
  select <- dplyr::select
  
  set.seed(10002)
  id <- sample(1:20, 1000, replace=T)
  
  set.seed(10003)
  group1 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
  
  set.seed(10004)
  group2 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)

  dummies <-
    data.frame(id, group1, group2)
```

## Current Approach

```
# I am trying to sum each column in a data frame by group and 
# set the value as 1 if the sum is not 0.

  dummies %>% 
    ddply('id', function(x){
      x %>% 
        select_if(is.numeric) %>%
        summarise_each(list(sum)) %>% 
        mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ifelse(.x > 0,1,.x))
    }, .progress = 'text') # It takes too much time
```

Comment: I think you can switch to dplyr instead of dplyr + plyr i.e. `dummies %>% group_by(id) %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), ~ +(sum(., na.rm = TRUE) > 0)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could possibly reduce the time by switching to `dplyr`.  Also, instead of doing the `sum` and then using `ifelse` to check and reconvert, this can be directly done by checking `any` value greater than 0

```
library(dplyr)
dummies %>% 
    dplyr::select(id, where(is.numeric)) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), ~ +(any(. > 0, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummies)[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
        +(any(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE))), id, .SDcols = patterns('group')]
```

Comment: As always, @akrun, your code works perfect. It was really fast computation. Thank you so much!!